# retain in python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which has a variable with values 0,1.

I need output in the following way.

Variable    -  0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0

Flag        -  1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4

Every time variable changes to 0 flag should increment by 1, and it should remain same till it encounters next 0.

I'm doing code conversion from SAS to python. It was pretty easy in SAS but I'm finding  it difficult in Pandas. Is there any specific retain function in pandas like SAS? I don't see any retain function in pandas documentation.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need compare with `0` and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
s = pd.Series([ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
print (s)
0     0
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     1
10    1
11    0
dtype: int64

s1 = (s == 0).cumsum()
print (s1)
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    4
dtype: int32
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable': [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]})
df['Flag'] = (df.Variable == 0).cumsum()
print (df)
    Variable  Flag
0          0     1
1          1     1
2          1     1
3          1     1
4          0     2
5          1     2
6          1     2
7          1     2
8          0     3
9          1     3
10         1     3
11         0     4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont want cumulative sum, I just want the flag variable value to increase by count 1 when it encounters 0 in variable column.

Comment: I am not sure if understand - need neww column? Then see last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pandas, just you can use loop,

Like this,

```
a='0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0'
flags=[]
flag=0
for i in list(a.split()):
    if int(i)==0:
        flag+=1
        flags.append(flag)
    else:
        flags.append(flag)

print flags
```

> > Output:
> >
> > [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]